# how send email by Pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracleforms

I want send email by using ***oracle 9i - Enterprise edition release 9.2.0.8.0 ,***I know there is one package for oracle 10,but would you advice me about it for oracle 9i? Is there any package ?

Can I sent email by **Oracle 9i?**
Is there any way using an interface program such as a java program and send email via that one, if it is impossible to send mail by **Oracle 9i...**

I mean I just send parameter to that program and send email by using that program.
I can run write batch file,can we run Outlook and send email via that one by Oracle 9i?

P.s. my database is base on 9i and my form builder is version 6.

Comment: There has never been a version of the Oracle database with a version of 6i.  The first version of the database to get a letter suffix was 8i (8.1.5).  There is a version of Oracle Forms that uses the marketing label 6i.  Oracle Forms would connect to an Oracle database where you would create the procedure to send email.  Oracle 6 is a thoroughly ancient version of Oracle-- it's been obsolete for 15-20 years.

Comment: Thanks bro,I double check it, you right, Our database is base on 9i. Now What is your suggestion?

Answer (score 5):

check this thread on asktom about sending emails (from version 8i+): "[Sending e-mail! -- Oracle 8i specific response](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::p11_question_id:255615160805)"

In version 9i, you have several options:

- using PL/SQL and the [UTL_SMTP](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96612/u_smtp.htm#1000695) package
- using a java procedure

The UTL_SMTP option would be the easiest to setup but some features (such as attaching files) may require a bit more work and some knowledge of SMTP. See [MikeyByCrikey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244117/how-send-email-by-pl-sql/4244538#4244538)'s answer for a good example.

If you plan to upgrade, APEX has some mail utility ([APEX_MAIL](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17556_01/doc/apirefs.40/e15519/apex_mail.htm#CIHDIEJI)) available for version 10g+.

Comment: There's not really a big problem with sending attachments but this requires a bit more work and understanding of SMTP

Comment: @andr: you're right, it's been a while since I've used this package. Mikey's example shows how to attach a file with UTL_SMTP.

Answer (score 4):

Oracle provides the [UTL_SMTP](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96612/u_smtp.htm) package which allows you to send mail. It requires access to a mail server of some description.

This package is a little complicated to use. There is a [supplied demo package](http://www.oracle.com/technology/sample_code/tech/pl_sql/htdocs/Utl_Smtp_Sample.html) that is available on the Oracle website which I am using successfully to send mail.

Answer (score 1):

Check this page from Burleson.

http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_email_mailing_messages_plsql.htm

Oracle has, since 8i, the system package utl_smtp for this, and since 10g, the utl_mail that expands this functionality.

Comment: Tempting to give -1 for mentioning Burleson, but that would be mean to a newcomer!

Comment: Even Burleson gets it right sometimes, but ok, you want AskTom, you get it:  http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1739411218448