# embedded scripting in PL/SQL for oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, shell, scripting, plsql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how send email by Pl/sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244117/how-send-email-by-pl-sql)

I want to send emails from within my pl/sql from the database using oracle 11g,sort of embedded scripting. please help. i'm not that familiar with oracle but i have a deadline to provide this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`UTL_MAIL` package](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_mail.htm) or the [`UTL_SMTP` package](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_smtp.htm) to send email from PL/SQL.  There are dozens of implementations floating around depending on exactly what your SMTP server requires, what sort of attachments you need to send, etc.  A good starting point is the [`send_mail` procedure from AskTom](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:255615160805).

If you are using APEX, you can also use the [`APEX_MAIL` package](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E10513_01/doc/apirefs.310/e12855/apex_mail.htm).