# How To send An Email thru Triggers in PL/SQL

Tags: plsql

I want to send email to a single recipient  thru triggers in pl/sql when any of the DML operation is performed.
may i know the code for it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how send email by Pl/sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244117/how-send-email-by-pl-sql)

Answer (score 0):

Generally you should not perform complex operations in triggers. Instead of insert a record into a table, which is processed by a separate job.

To send email from the separate job use the UTL_SMTP package.